# Scaling in heat transfer PDE and dimensionless group

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, heat-equation, dimensional-analysis

I found the following in my **Scaling in Heat Transfer** notes:

> **Rod Conduction**
>
> A rod of length $L$ initially at $T_0$ then (at $t = 0$) one end is raised to $T_1$. Find $T(x, t)$.
>
> $$T_t = \kappa T_{x x}$$
>
> **Scaling**
>
> We write
>
> $$x = Lx', \ t = \tau t', \ T = T_0 + (T_1 - T_0) T'(x', t')$$
>
> with $\tau$ as yet unknown. This gives
>
> $$T'_{t'} = \left[ \dfrac{\kappa \tau}{L^2} \right] T'_{x' x'}$$
>
> There is one dimensionless group $[\cdot]$ and if we choose $\tau = \dfrac{L^2}{\kappa}$ we get the dimensionless problem.

What I'm confused about is how they got $T'_{t'} = \left[ \dfrac{\kappa \tau}{L^2} \right] T'_{x' x'}$? We do have $T_t = \kappa T_{x x}$, but how did $\kappa$ get replace with the dimensionless group $\left[ \dfrac{\kappa \tau}{L^2} \right]$? How is this justified? What is the reasoning behind this change?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original PDE is

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = [\kappa] \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$$

By the chain rule, the left hand side is:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial t'}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial t'} \frac{1}{\tau}$$

Applying the chain rule *twice* to the right hand side:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial T}{\partial x'} \frac{1}{L}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}) = \frac{1}{L} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}) = \frac{1}{L^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x'}(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x'})  = \frac{1}{L^2} (\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x'^2})$$

Subtituting into the PDE

$$\frac{1}{\tau} \frac{\partial T}{\partial t'} = \left[\frac{\kappa}{L^2}\right] \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x'^2}$$

Or

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t'} = \left[\frac{\kappa \tau}{L^2}\right] \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x'^2}$$

Hope that helps